# lxml xpath on new element yields empty list

Tags: python, lxml

Say I am composing a xml based on a incomplete xml that lives on a file. I go over each element trying to find it or else creating it.

```
  if len(list(root.xpath(COMSTACK_XPATH, namespaces=NS))) == 0:
    create_com_stack_subelement(root.xpath(CDDROOT_XPATH, namespaces=NS).pop())
```

If the element gets created I'd like to repeat a similar operation, this time searching for the newly created element and in turn adding subelements to it.

The problem is that any xpath pointing to the new element wont work unless I write the tree into a file and parse it back.

Is this expected? I am using lxml==4.9.2

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to tell with the limited information you've provided. Please [edit] your question and post a self-contained [mre] including example data as well as all imports and function/variable definitions. Keep in mind that `root` is (most likely, you didn't show the code) the object representing the originally parsed XML. Unless you're modifying it directly, it won't see the changes.

Comment: It has to do with namespaces. I create the new elements using ``` xnew = etree.SubElement(parent, 'ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE', attrib={'UUID': str(uuid.uuid4())}, nsmap={None:'http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'})``` and the xpath works if I remove the namespace prefix from the xpath part of the new elements

Answer (score 0):

While trying to enhance the information of my question I stumbled upon the answer. It turned out I was adding Elements without the namespace, once I started using etree.QName everything started working

```
 xnew = etree.SubElement(parent, etree.QName('URI', 'CONTAINER'), attrib={'UUID': str(uuid.uuid4())})
```